# How to set multiple edge lengths to one measurement

Tags: edit-mode, edges, scale, units

I have a project im working on and every edge length is random. I would like to be able to enter a numerical value to set every edge to the same length. All edges are connected to vertices.

I tried using the "set edge length" tool but said it was not allowed on edges shared with vertices.

Blender 2.9

Comment: Hello, could you add a bit more info about your setup ? a screenshot would help too

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I don't even know the "set edge length" tool. The only thing I can imagine is, when you set an edge length it gets scaled with its center as pivot point - which means, to make it longer the vertices move further apart or come closer to each other to make the edge shorter. But if you have to edges sharing one vertex, this one vertex had to move in opposite directions for scaling both edges, which is not possible. Or the tool must have an option to define the shared vertex as pivot point.